# Destroying $interval in a directive

Tags: node.js, angularjs-directive, intervals

I have an $interval that needs to be destroyed. I am using the $interval in a directive.

First Q. How can I destroy the interval in a directive?

I am using the interval to create a timer, and I want to get it destroyed when the countdown reaches some date.

Second Q. How can I fire an event when the timer goes off?

Thanks in advance!

DIRECTIVE

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('time', ['timeUtil', 'timeEpoch', '$interval', function(timeUtil, timeEpoch, $interval) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { date: '@' },

        link: function(scope, element) {        
            $interval(function() {
                var diff = timeEpoch.diff(scope.date); // calculate some time
                return element.text(timeUtil.dhms(diff)); // return formatted date to countdown
            }, 1000);
        }
   }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

To destroy the interval you have the option

```
$interval.cancel([promise]);
```

This will be like

```
 $scope.StopTimer = function () {

            //Do your task here

            //Cancel the Timer.
            $interval.cancel($scope.Timer);
        };
```

You can have a look on these links

1) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

2)http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AngularJS-interval-example-How-to-Start-Stop-and-Cancel-Destroy-interval-in-AngularJS.aspx